# Control center not working in portrait mode (iPad 2)?

Tags: ios, ipad, control-center

I just upgraded my iPad 2 WiFi to iOS 7.0.4 and noticed this bug that's really strange:

No matter what I do, I can't bring up the control center when the iPad is in **portrait** mode. When in landscape, it will come up with a swipe just fine!

More bizarre, when I hold it upside down (the front camera on the button), the control center also shows!

Anybody has any idea what's going on and is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: Did you try rebooting the iPad ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler, it was the first thing that I did. I even restored it again. No luck.